# How parse email and get hyperlink from mail JavaMail?

Tags: selenium, jakarta-mail, imap

After spending a lot of time in finding a solution to their problem and I have not found a solution. In general, the problem is as follows:
There is a web application where you can send an invitation to work on the project, the standard form filling data including e-mail which will be sent. And so the task to cover the auto test this functionality. Initially I thought to do it all on selenium'e after sending an invitation to open a new instanst browser, go to the postal service which will be sent an invitation and there manipulate the search and the discovery of the letter, invite, and pressing the button. I understand that it's a bit tugovato process and found a solution to their problem is to use the JavaMail library to receive messages. Ie to connect to the mail service in this example I use Gmail, and from there get all the letters.

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesEmail {

String host = "imap.gmail.com";
String user = "userEmail";
String password = "password";
int port = 993;

public Properties setServerProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    return properties;
}

}

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CheckUnreadEmail {

public static void checkUnreadEmail(){

    try{

        //Create object email properties
        PropertiesEmail propertiesEmail = new PropertiesEmail();

        //Set email server properties
        Properties props = propertiesEmail.setServerProperties();

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        Store store = session.getStore();

        store.connect(propertiesEmail.host, propertiesEmail.user, propertiesEmail.password);

        //Create the folder object and open it
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        //Total unread messages
        System.out.println("Total messages: " + folder.getMessageCount());
        System.out.println("Unread messages: " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());


        //Create variable for search unread message
        FlagTerm flag = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);

        //Retrieve all messages
        //Message [] messages = folder.getMessages();

        //Retrieve unread messages from the folder INBOX
        Message [] unreadMessage = folder.search(flag);

        for (int i = 0, n = unreadMessage.length; i < n; i++){
            Message message = unreadMessage[i];
            System.out.println("--------------");
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
        }

        //folder.setFlags(unreadMessage, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);

        //close the store and folder objects
        folder.close(false);
        store.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

There are a few questions:
1. How to wait for a new letter in the mail? (Since after sending the email invitation does not come at once)
2. How to parse received the letter and get a hyperlink to an invite?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's [clean up your code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  You're setting the default Store protocol to be `imaps`, which means that all the `mail.imap.*` properties are being ignored.  And most of them don't matter since you're passing the connection details to the connect method explicitly.

To wait for a new message to arrive, you can either poll, or you can use the [IMAP IDLE command](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle--).  The [JavaMail monitor.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) shows how to do both.

JavaMail isn't going to help you with parsing the content of the received message.  You can just use simple string processing or regular expressions, which is probably good enough for this case.  Or, you can look for a Java library that will parse HTML.